# Track webpage in background

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, android-webview, google-analytics-api

I want to design an app based on a web-service, also I want to open some background page according to web-service data via `WebView` to be able to track that pages in `GoogleAnalytics`.

To accomplish this ideas I wrote the following singleton and It's work as I expected but there is strange memory leak behavior in this code that I assume it caused form `WebView` bug!

```
public class SiteLoader {
    private static SiteLoader mSiteLoader;

    private WebView mWebView;

    private Context c;

    public enum LoaderUri {
        MUSIC_URI, VIDEO_URI, BOOK_URI
    }

    private SiteLoader(Context c) {
        this.c = c.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static SiteLoader getInstance(Context c) {
        if (mSiteLoader == null)
            mSiteLoader = new SiteLoader(c);

        return mSiteLoader;
    }

    public void trackUri(LoaderUri uri, String extraData) {
        // Load new progress
        switch (uri) {
            case MUSIC_URI:
                getWebView().loadUrl(Constants.HOST_PREFIX + "/music/?id=" + extraData);
                break;
            case VIDEO_URI:
                getWebView().loadUrl(Constants.HOST_PREFIX + "/video/?id=" + extraData);
                break;
            case BOOK_URI:
                getWebView().loadUrl(Constants.HOST_PREFIX + "/book/?id=" + extraData);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void destroyTracker() {
        if (mWebView != null) {
             mWebView.destroy();
             mWebView = null;
        }
    }

    private WebView getWebView() {
        if (mWebView == null) {
            mWebView = new WebView(c);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }

        return mWebView;
    }
}
```

Any ideas to how get rid from this situation or is there any other alternative way to tack the page directly in `web-service`?

Test case activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override 
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SiteLoader.getInstance(this).trackUri(LoaderUri.VIDEO_URI, "en");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onPause() {
        super.onResume();
        SiteLoader.getInstance(this).destroyTracker();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle mBundle) {
        super.onCreate(mBundle);
        Toast.makeText(this, "System is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you run your app inside Eclipse MAT to see where the leak is coming from?

Comment: @ksasq I know where it comes form, according to this topic http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181 it's related to WebView bug and unfortunately the workaround which provided in this link is no longer working!

Comment: Have you verified with MAT you are hitting the same issue though? That issue does not mention WebView that I can see. And please provide more detail - which version of the Android platform are you seeing the leak? Does it reproduce on all versions?

Comment: In your application are you using more than one web-view? If it is, than it is possible as web-view consumes more memory compared to other component.

Comment: @AnilSavaj No, there is just one `WebView` all over that app and the above class is a singleton.

Comment: @ksasq Yup, by the way you can test the above code and see memory usage in android task manager - I'm currently using android 4.4.2.

Comment: Interesting it reproduces on 4.4.2. If you use MAT rather than the task manager it will identify what object is leaking, and why it's being retained.

Comment: @ksasq I have no access to MAT right now, could you please test it?

Comment: If you can share a debug APK with me, yes.

Comment: @ksasq Due to off-topics terms I can't send you the file but the current apk consists the above class and a activity to test, just it!

Comment: The content of the "activity to test" is what I'm missing. I don't know what methods you are calling, how you use the SiteLoader, even how to reproduce the bug. Sorry I don't think I can help if you cannot provide a reduced test case. :-(

Comment: @ksasq Yes, you're right - I add my test case activity to above post, please check it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47431/discussion-between-ksasq-and-isun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with the OP, it appears that there is no memory leak per se in this case; rather that the WebView is a memory intensive component that consumes a relatively high amount of RAM when used.